# How do I handle multiple environments in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-fargate, amazon-ecr, aws-codecommit

I prepared all my staging environment in aws and now I'm trying to setup production. I found that it's better to have 2 accounts in different availability zones as it's explained in this question: [aws in production and development environments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62641547/how-do-i-handle-development-and-production-environments-in-aws)

So my staging account is in eu-central-1 and I want to setup production in eu-west-1.

I met different difficulties.

First of all I don't think that it's good idea to have 2 source controls. So I left all the sources in codecommit in eu-central-1. Code build also produces only one container which is in eu-central-1 as well. I made a new s3 bucket in eu-west-1 with file containing production environment variables and another file containing git secrets. I updated fargate execution role to have access to the new resources. Still when I tried to run the new fargate service which resides in eu-west-1 I receive the following error:

ResourceInitializationError: unable to pull secrets or registry auth: execution resource retrieval failed: unable to retrieve ecr registry auth: service call has been retried 3 time(s): RequestError: send request failed caused by: Post https://api.ecr.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/:  i/o timeout

I see I can't pull image from eu-central-1. I might miss something small but my problems is that I might doing everything totally wrong. Any advice will be much appreciated.

Comment: I'm not seeing any mention of different regions (which you mistakenly call different availability zones in your question) in the answer you linked to. Why would you want your staging and production environments to be in different regions? They would end up possibly having different services available. I can't think of any real advantage to splitting them between regions. Having environments in different accounts is a good idea. An alternative, would be to have them in the same account but in different regions.

Comment: Also your question mentions sharing CodeCommit, but then goes on to list an error with an ECR pull, which is totally unrelated to CodeCommit. Then you go on to say the error is probably due to the regions, when it is probably actually an issue with ECR being in a different account, not really related to the region the ECR repo is in.